# Session lost when redirect from Facebook's login at https when developing an iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook, session, ssl, oauth

**Hi**, everyone

I am developing an iPhone app which could login with Facebook, Twitter account by users.

I am using the server-side flow to deal with the login process.
Of course, I also set the *Website URL* at Facebook(oauth2.0) side and *Callback URL* at Twitter(oauth1.0a) side and with no problem when using *http*.

Our company contracted for a ssl. Then, I changed the *http* to *https* in the Facebook side or Twitter side, and changed my post url for login from *http* to *https*.
But when redirect from theirs login screen, I lost all data in session which I stored such as token information before login.

For test, I am also using browser(IE) to check the login behavior, and it has no problem both at *http* and *https* cases.

Bay the way, whatever the client is browser(IE) or iPhone app, the server-side source code is the same.

So what is the problem, please?